# Identifying/Managing users based on session ID (Mapping between Session ID to User ID to User Data)

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, oauth, session-cookies

I wrote a web-app that authenticated a user via Facebook connect (o-Auth).
After the user have authenticated I have a facebook token.
Using this token I send a request to Facebook to grab its basic user information.
At this point I have the user unique Facebook id and I know who it is.

1. How should I link between the user, the token and it's data in the database?
   Right now my schema is pretty simple: facebook_id is the Primary key, and there are some other columns that includes the token and the user's data. Is that the correct way to do it?
2. At which point do I need to set a unique SESSION_ID (cookie) on the user request? After it authenticated?
   I am confused about this part (and with Session management in general). When i set an attribute on a session does the browser remember it an send it in every request to my server? across all pages?
3. And the most important question is, how do i map between the SESSION ID and the user? Once i set a session id on his request, i need to figure out on every request who it is. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That is fine, all you really want to do is to be able to match to a particular Facebook User ID with the data created by or in your web app that doesn't come from the Graph API .
2. At the moment you complete the Login flow (when you receive the Access Token). When you set a session the browser will remember the key-value pair in it until the session is cleared. So you want your code to be able to associate someone using a browser with a particular user in your database (or not if they don't have a session). Thus, whatever session value you use, you need to also store this in the Database alongside the User ID.
3. See above.

Honestly though, the very easiest way of doing this is to just use the Facebook Javascript SDK. This will handle all the access token retrieval and user persistence through cookies automatically, without you having to write code for it. Ultimately this will mean that all you need to do is store the Facebook User ID in your database alongside the app-generated content and won't need to worry about storing access tokens or session variables. There's a simple step-by-step guide here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/
(in Step 5 you'll receive the User ID and you can make an AJAX call to server-side code from here to store it in your database)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer.
I am doing the server-side login, so it's a little bit more tricky. Since the server is doing all the calls to facebook on behalf of the user.
Just wasn't sure how to maintain the session, but your answer helped.

Comment: There is a guide to Server-side login flow here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/ it uses PHP but it is a generic process, so you can adapt the steps into your own language easily. Also, Step 6 in that doc is probably specifically what you're looking for.

Comment: I implemented this flow (from the guide you linked, in java), and it works great.
The problem was how to identify the user after all this flow ends. I need to set him a session identifier so he will send it to me on every request. Wasn't sure at which point i need to set it.